# Using longtable inside xparse \NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: longtable, xparse

I am trying to create a wrapper for the `longtable` environment and it works fine with the standard `\newenvironment` command. Now I want to use `\NewDocumentEnvironment` from the `xparse` package to allow more optional arguments. But the result looks different, there appears an additional cell below the table. Maybe it's caused by a linebreak from the `\NewDocumentEnvironment` command because the error doesn't appear when I move the `\end{longtable}` from the end-code-block to the start-code-block of the environment definition (like I did in the example in `myxparsetable2` environment).

I created a minimal example.
The error appears with `myxparsetable1`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{longtable}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myxparsetable1}{m}
{\begin{longtable}{#1}}
{\end{longtable}}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myxparsetable2}{}
{%
  \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|} \hline%
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline%
  \end{longtable}%
}
{}

\newenvironment{mytable}[1]
{\begin{longtable}{#1}}
{\end{longtable}}

\begin{document}

  Normal longtable:
  \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|} \hline
    col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
  \end{longtable}

  Custom mytable
  \begin{mytable}{|c|c|c|} \hline
      col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
  \end{mytable}

  Custom myxparsetable1
  \begin{myxparsetable1}{|c|c|c|} \hline
      col1 & col2 & col3 \\ \hline
  \end{myxparsetable1}

  Custom myxparsetable2
  \begin{myxparsetable2}
  \end{myxparsetable2}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:
[image: Output from minimal example]

Comment: It's a known problem: with `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}`, the macro `\endfoo`, that's internally used by LaTeX when `\end{foo}` is found, is `\protected`, so LaTeX starts a new row before realizing that the table should end. For the time being, use `\newenvironment` for environments involving tables.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and good answer. Do you know a way to use more than one optional argument with \newenvironment? Thanks Martin

Comment: I forgot to say “Welcome to TeX.SX”!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known problem: with `\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}`, the macro `\endfoo`, that's internally used by LaTeX when `\end{foo}` is processed is “protected” and, because of this, LaTeX can't see that the alignment is to be ended until it has already started a new row.

The situation is mostly similar to having `\multicolumn` not as the first item in a cell.

What can I offer, if you want to scan multiple arguments for `\begin{foo}`, a kludge:

```
\newenvironment{myxparsetable}{}{\end{longtable}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\myxparsetable}{mO{}o}{%
  ...something with #2 and #3...
  \begin{longtable}{#1}
}
```

Comment: That works fine for me! Thank you very much for your help.